# Adding color scale using add_heatmap in googleway

Tags: r, heatmap, googleway

I am creating heatmap using `googleway`. For example, for the tram_route example given in the help of `?add_heatmap`, how can I add a color scale so that the reader knows what is the number associated with that color?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

#### Note:

As of 2017-10-04 the legend is still in development and is subject to change, and may not be 100% fully functional yet.

#### Installation

```
devtools::install_github("SymbolixAU/googleway")
library(googleway)
```

#### Examples

```
set.seed(20170417)
df <- tram_route
df$weight <- sample(1:10, size = nrow(df), replace = T)

google_map(key = map_key, data = df) %>%
  add_heatmap(lat = "shape_pt_lat", lon = "shape_pt_lon", weight = "weight",
              option_radius = 0.001, legend = T)
```

[image]

```
## specifying different colour gradient
option_gradient <- c('orange', 'blue', 'mediumpurple4', 'snow4', 'thistle1')

google_map(key = map_key, data = df) %>%
 add_heatmap(lat = "shape_pt_lat", lon = "shape_pt_lon", weight = "weight",
              option_radius = 0.001, option_gradient = option_gradient, legend = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah Cool! Thank you. I will try it out and look forward to the release!

Comment: @L.Yang if you have any comments or issues feel free to let me know [on the issues page](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues/32)